# String.join() vs other string concatenation operations

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have quickly read over the Java8 [String api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation.

Now I am little curious about String.join() method to concat/join strings.

This kind of example has helped me to understand better, though:

```
//Old way:
String str1 = "John";
String str2 = "Doe";
String result = str1 + " " +str2;
//or by using str1.concat(str2);

//New way:
String result = String.join(" ", str1, str2);
```

Still, I don't understand which one should I use. Is there any performance or other differences between these two processes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `concat` does not contemplate delimiters, and `join` can be performed over multiple strings. Also note that concatenating multiple with + may not result in `concat` operations over strings.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`String.join` relies on the class [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) which itself relies on an internal `StringBuilder` to build the joined string.

So performance-wise it's much the same as using a `StringBuilder` and appending to it, or using a chain of `+` (which nowadays are converted to `StringBuilder` operations by the compiler).

But the significance of `String.join` is not as a general replacement for `+` or `String.concat`, but in being the "reverse operation" of a `String.split` operation. It makes more sense in that context - when you have a bunch of strings that you want to join together using a delimiter - than as a replacement for `concat`.

That is, to build an output like `"a/b/c/d"` or `"(a+b+c+d)"` when you have `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` in an array or a list, `String.join` or a `StringJoiner` would make the operation clear and readable.

Comment: Note that it's not *specified* anywhere that `StringJoiner` relies on `StringBuilder`. In particular in OpenJDK9 it's optimized and doesn't use `StringBuilder` anymore.

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes, I was basing that information on reading the current source code.

Answer (score 3):

`str1 + " " + str2` is internally converted into:

```
StringBuffer tmp1 = new StringBuffer();
tmp1.append(str1);
tmp1.append(" ");
String tmp2 = tmp1.toString();
StringBuffer tmp3 = new StringBuffer();
tmp3.append(tmp2);
tmp3.append(str2);
String result = tmp3.toString();
```

`str1.concat(str2)` will not produce the same result, as the space wont be present between the two strings.

join should be equivalent to

```
StringBuffer tmp1 = new StringBuffer();
tmp1.append(str1);
tmp1.append(" ");
tmp1.append(str2);
String result = tmp.toString();
```

and hence be faster.

Comment: `+` is converted into `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`. Same for `join`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use StringJoiner (Java8+)

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class StringJoinerTest {

public static final String FILESEPARATOR = ", ";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(FILESEPARATOR);
    sj.add("Test1");
    sj.add("Test2");
    sj.add("Test3");
    System.out.println(sj);
   }
}
```

Output is

```
Test1, Test2, Test3
```