# Why is 'new_file += line + string' so much faster than 'new_file = new_file + line + string'?

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation, cpython, python-internals

Our code takes 10 minutes to siphon thru 68,000 records when we use:

```
new_file = new_file + line + string
```

However when we do the following it takes just 1 second:

```
new_file += line + string
```

Here is the code:

```
for line in content:
import time
import cmdbre

fname = "STAGE050.csv"
regions = cmdbre.regions
start_time = time.time()
with open(fname) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        new_file_content = ""
        new_file = open("CMDB_STAGE060.csv", "w")
        row_region = ""
        i = 0
        for line in content:
                if (i==0):
                        new_file_content = line.strip() + "~region" + "\n"
                else:
                        country = line.split("~")[13]
                        try:
                                row_region = regions[country]
                        except KeyError:
                                row_region = "Undetermined"
                        new_file_content += line.strip() + "~" + row_region + "\n"
                print (row_region)
                i = i + 1
        new_file.write(new_file_content)
        new_file.close()
        end_time = time.time()
        print("total time: " + str(end_time - start_time))
```

All code I've ever written in python uses the first option. This is just basic string operations... we are reading input from a file, processing it and outputting it to the new file. I am 100% certain that the first method takes roughly 600 times longer to run than the second, but why?

The file being processed is a csv but uses ~ instead of a comma. All we are doing here is taking this csv, which has a column for country, and adding a column for the countries region, e.g. LAC, EMEA, NA, etc... cmdbre.regions is just a dictionary, with all ~200 countries as the key and each region as the value.

Once I changed to the append string operation... the loop completed in 1 second instead of 10 minutes... 68,000 records in the csv.

Comment: are you sure you're using strings? not lists?

Comment: in-place string addition shouldn't be faster, because strings are immutable. So I've a doubt about type of the data.

Comment: What version of Python, on which platform? Please attach a minimal script that replicates this issue.

Comment: if you think it's fast, just try `io.StringIO` or put your lines in a list and use `"".join()` in the end.

Comment: @ymbirtt negative.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: CPython has an optimization that breaks the immutability guarantees in cases where there is only a single reference (so from an outside perspective, there is no meaningful difference if it mutates the string).

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings

Comment: Can anyone actually replicate the time difference? @ShadowRanger says the optimization is for both `a += b` and `a = a+ b`. The OP needs to show their code with timings and their system details.

Comment: Python 3. Added more details as requested above.

Comment: @user3656612: Yeah, you broke the optimization. I've updated my answer to address how, and how you could fix it (though the real fix is "Use `+=` when it describes what you are doing").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CPython (the reference interpreter) has an optimization for in-place string concatenation (when the string being appended to has no other references). It can't apply this optimization as reliably when doing `+`, only `+=` (`+` involves two live references, the assignment target and the operand, and the former isn't involved in the `+` operation, so it's harder to optimize it).

You shouldn't rely on this though, per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Code should be written in a way that does not disadvantage other implementations of Python (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, Cython, Psyco, and such).
>
> For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of in-place string concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a = a + b . This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for some types) and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the ''.join() form should be used instead. This will ensure that concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

**Update based on question edits**: Yeah, you broke the optimization. You concatenated many strings, not just one, and Python evaluates left-to-right, so it must do the left-most concatenation first. Thus:

```
new_file_content += line.strip() + "~" + row_region + "\n"
```

is not at all the same as:

```
new_file_content = new_file_content + line.strip() + "~" + row_region + "\n"
```

because the former concatenates all the *new* pieces together, then appends them to the accumulator string all at once, while the latter must evaluate each addition from left to right with temporaries that don't involve `new_file_content` itself. Adding parens for clarity, it's like you did:

```
new_file_content = (((new_file_content + line.strip()) + "~") + row_region) + "\n"
```

Because it doesn't actually know the types until it reaches them, it can't assume all of those are strings, so the optimization doesn't kick in.

If you changed the second bit of code to:

```
new_file_content = new_file_content + (line.strip() + "~" + row_region + "\n")
```

or slightly slower, but still many times faster than your slow code because it keeps the CPython optimization:

```
new_file_content = new_file_content + line.strip()
new_file_content = new_file_content + "~"
new_file_content = new_file_content + row_region
new_file_content = new_file_content + "\n"
```

so the accumulation was obvious to CPython, you'd fix the performance problem. But frankly, you should just be using `+=` anytime you're performing a logical append operation like this; `+=` exists for a reason, and it provides useful information to both the maintainer and the interpreter. Beyond that, it's good practice as far as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) goes; why name the variable twice when you don't need to?

Of course, per PEP8 guidelines, even using `+=` here is bad form. In most languages with immutable strings (including most non-CPython Python interpreters), repeated string concatenation is a form of [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm), which causes serious performance problems. The correct solution is to build a `list` of strings, then `join` them all at one, e.g.:

```
    new_file_content = []
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        if i==0:
            # In local tests, += anonymoustuple runs faster than
            # concatenating short strings and then calling append
            # Python caches small tuples, so creating them is cheap,
            # and using syntax over function calls is also optimized more heavily
            new_file_content += (line.strip(), "~region\n")
        else:
            country = line.split("~")[13]
            try:
                    row_region = regions[country]
            except KeyError:
                    row_region = "Undetermined"
            new_file_content += (line.strip(), "~", row_region, "\n")

    # Finished accumulating, make final string all at once
    new_file_content = "".join(new_file_content)
```

which is usually faster even when the CPython string concatenation options are available, and will be reliably fast on non-CPython Python interpreters as well because it uses a mutable `list` to accumulate results efficiently, then allows `''.join` to precompute the total length of the string, allocate the final string all at once (instead of incremental resizes along the way), and populate it exactly once.

Side-note: For your specific case, you shouldn't be accumulating or concatenating at all. You've got an input file and an output file, and can process line by line. Every time you would append or accumulate file contents, just write them out instead (I've cleaned up the code a bit for PEP8 compliance and other minor style improvements while I was at it):

```
start_time = time.monotonic()  # You're on Py3, monotonic is more reliable for timing

# Use with statements for both input and output files
with open(fname) as f, open("CMDB_STAGE060.csv", "w") as new_file:
    # Iterate input file directly; readlines just means higher peak memory use
    # Maintaining your own counter is silly when enumerate exists
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if not i:
            # Write to file directly, don't store
            new_file.write(line.strip() + "~region\n")
        else:
            country = line.split("~")[13]
            # .get exists to avoid try/except when you have a simple, constant default
            row_region = regions.get(country, "Undetermined")
            # Write to file directly, don't store
            new_file.write(line.strip() + "~" + row_region + "\n")
end_time = time.monotonic()
# Print will stringify arguments and separate by spaces for you
print("total time:", end_time - start_time)
```

### Implementation details deep dive

For those curious on implementation details, the CPython string concat optimization is implemented in the byte code interpreter, not on the `str` type itself (technically, `PyUnicode_Append` does the mutation optimization, but it requires help from the interpreter to fix up reference counts so it knows it can use the optimization safely; without interpreter help, only C extension modules would ever benefit from that optimization).

When the interpreter [detects that both operands are the Python level `str` type](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/ceval.c#l1763) (at C layer, in Python 3, it's still referred to as `PyUnicode`, a legacy of 2.x days that wasn't worth changing), it calls [a special `unicode_concatenate` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/ceval.c#l5278), which checks whether the very next instruction is one of three basic `STORE_*` instructions. If it is, and the target is the same as the left operand, it clears the target reference so `PyUnicode_Append` will see only a single reference to the operand, allowing it to invoke the optimized code for a `str` with a single reference.

This means that not only can you break the optimization by doing

```
a = a + b + c
```

you can also break it any time the variable in question is not a top level (global, nested or local) name. If you're operating on an object attribute, a `list` index, a `dict` value, etc., even `+=` won't help you, it won't see a "simple `STORE`", so it doesn't clear the target reference, and all of these get the ultraslow, not-in-place behavior:

```
foo.x += mystr
foo[0] += mystr
foo['x'] += mystr
```

It's also specific to the `str` type; in Python 2, the optimization doesn't help with `unicode` objects, and in Python 3, it doesn't help with `bytes` objects, and in neither version will it optimize for subclasses of `str`; those always take the slow path.

Basically, the optimization is there to be as nice as possible in the simplest common cases for people new to Python, but it's not going to go to serious trouble for even moderately more complex cases. This just reinforces the PEP8 recommendation: Depending on implementation details of your interpreter is a bad idea when you could run faster on *every* interpreter, for any store target, by doing the right thing and using `str.join`.

Comment: The PEP claims it can optimize `a = a + b` as well and my local tests show this to be the case on Python 3.5.2 on Linux x64. It's possible this varies by CPython version, or your particular test is breaking that optimization in some subtle way.

Comment: Great answer, very insightful, but can you clarify what would be a minimalist example where the optimization does not kick in? like `a += b + c` vs. `a = a + b + c` or similar?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's an implementation detail, so there are no guarantees (CPython provides no guarantees on this optimization at all), but yeah, in general, as soon as you're looking at `a = a + b + c` the optimization is broken (my local tests were for this form, except I didn't even use variables for `b` and `c`, it was just `s = s + "abc" + "d"`).

Comment: As my local tests show, this optimization loss applies even if `b` and `c` are actually string literals, not variable names (which a compiled language with an optimizing compiler could pre-concatenate); Python can't do this because at compile time, it doesn't know the type of `s`/`new_file_contents`, and it guarantees left-to-right evaluation order. If it's a type with overloaded `__add__`/`+`, the result of `s + "abc" + "d"` could be very different from `s + "abcd"`, so it _must_ evaluate each addition individually, and the intermediate temporary results break the string concat optimization.

Comment: This is a very interesting and deep answer. I really appreciate it. I can't say for certain, but I think I recall that join type operations where actually the slowest way to do this in other languages. Regardless of the language I'm using, I've always used the a = a + b method only because its 100% clear to the reader what I am doing. But this answer really provides a seriously great deal of value to me. I have 3 other projects that are going to benefit from these consideration. Up vote indeed sir.

Comment: @user3656612: Well, aside from Python, [`C#`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21078/364696) ([2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fyuan/2012/08/14/performance-tips-faster-than-stringbuilder/)) and [at least some Java runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817290/string-join-vs-other-string-concatenation-operations#comment51579967_31817569) have faster `join`. I'd expect the same for any language with immutable string types. [Perl has mutable strings and `join` still seems to win](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=964608).

Comment: That said, even when it wins, `join` wins _asymptotically_, it doesn't _always_ win. One concatenation is going to be faster than building a two-tuple and `join`-ing it. If you're collecting a ton of strings, then joining, and your language either has a poorly optimized amortized growth dynamic array type, or must copy each string to store it (pre-C++11 C++ had this issue for `std::vector<std::string>`, as would C++11 if your store didn't invoke r-value stores), then losses elsewhere would cancel any `join` gains. Aside from that, for "large enough" input, `join` should win.

Comment: @user3656612: In any event, please consider using `+=` when you're performing a logically in-place operation. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) is a rule for a reason; `a = a + b` is easy to read, but for longer names, repeating the name twice and using assignment instead of increment means people need to make sure it's the same variable, not two similarly named variables, and make sure operator precedence isn't changing behavior (e.g. `a = a + b +c` actually _did_ change behavior vs. `a += b + c` here). And of course, for mutable types, `+=` is efficient and in-place, `+` is neither.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, both could be equally slow, but for some optimization which are actually an implementation detail on the official Python runtime (cPython).

Strings in Python are immutable - that means that when you do "str1 + str2", Python has to create a third string object, and copy over all the contents from str1 and from str2 to it - no matter how large any of these parts is.

The inplace operator allows Python to use some internal optimizations so that all data in str1 is not necessarily copied over again - and probably it even allows some buffer space for further concatenation options.

When one gets the feeling on how the language works, the way to build a large text body from small strings is to create a Python list with all the strings, and after the looping is over, make a single call to the `str.join` method passing in all string components. That will be consistently fast, even across Python implementations, and not depending on optimizations to be able to be triggered.

```
output = []
for ...:
    output.append(line)

new_file = "\n".join(output)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this makes the most sense. when you do a = a + b 60,000 times python is loading a into the cpu or rams memory each and every time. When a gets big, the operation gets slow. += probably keeps it there or adds pointers or something. Still very surprised... most other languages I've worked in wouldn't produce different times under this scenario.

Comment: @user3656612: Few other languages try to optimize this. You'd definitely suffer if you did this in C++; `+=` is significantly faster there than `+`, because C++ strings are mutable, and the overallocate to optimize for repeated concatenation, while `+` requires creating whole new `string` objects.