# How string concatenation works in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

Why does `f` work much faster than `g`?

```
def f(n):
    s = ''
    for i in range(n):
        s = s + 'x'
    return s

def g(n):
    s, t = '', ''
    for i in range(n // 2):
        s = t + 'x'
        t = s + 'x'
    return t

print(len(f(500000))) - 0.1s
print(len(g(500000))) - 7.684s
```

Return values are the same. Why `f` has linear complexity, but `g` quadratic?

Comment: CPython has a special case optimization for the case of `x += y` or `x = x + y` where `x` and `y` are a `str` (`y` can be an expression that results in a `str`, e.g. `x += 'a' + 'bcd'`) and there are no other references to it; CPython mutates the `str` in place (technically against the rules, but with no other references, it's not breaking observed behaviors).

Comment: Yes ShadowRanger wrote an excellent related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996908/6260170

Comment: Incidentally, the *time complexity* isn't changing I think, although the *computation time* is

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It really does change if the strings are overallocated for the purpose.