# Complexity of string += operation

Tags: python, string, cpython

I am kinda confused. I was sure that due do immutability of `str` operation like `s += "abc"` need to copy whole `s` content to another place in memory so effectively adding character to very long string will consume much time.

I wrote snippet to prove my theory:

```
import timeit

def foo(i):
    res = ""
    for _ in range(i):
        res += "a"  
    return res


def foo2(i):
    res = []
    for _ in range(i):
        res.append("a")
    return "".join(res)


iterations = 100000
print(timeit.timeit('foo(iterations)', globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit.timeit('foo2(iterations)', globals=globals(), number=100))
```

However it looks like

1. `foo` execution time grows linearly based on `iterations`
2. `foo2` is like just two times faster than `foo`

I tried to inspect bytecode searching for some hidden optimizations. I tried to change constant string to randomized one with proper length to deny interning as well but couldn't find any explanation of that behaviour.

Was I wrong then? Does `+=` depend on string length or not? If so, how can I prove that?

Comment: On my machine, foo2 is 25% faster than foo.  At the bottom level, these two options aren't very different.  BOTH of these will have to keep reallocating memory as the set grows.  Allocating a new object is a relatively minor part of the time.  Copying the memory is the expensive part.  Lists start out with a LITTLE padding, but they also have to allocate new memory as the list grows.

Comment: In that case - yes, but if it's the case the difference should grow when we add much longer strings (so list doesn't have to copy memory so ofter). But in reality it doesn't change that difference.

Comment: CPython-3, as the only Python implementation to my knowledge, contains an internal optimization for the string `+=` anti-pattern. Explained in this blog post, for example: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/string-concat.html

Comment: @TimRoberts: List `append`s are guaranteed amortized `O(1)`, where concatenating immutable `str` is rather the opposite (the spec strongly suggests it *should* be `O(n)` on a logical basis). CPython just provides a special-case optimization for when violations of the immutability guarantees can't cause problems (they can be detected by comparing `id`s before and after, but you can't cause an alias to appear to change). The `list` reallocation remains fairly trivial (because it occurs less and less as the `list` grows).

Comment: @Homer512: The only Python implementation? There are *several*, though many of them are in varying states of decay, support-wise. Pypy remains moderately modern though, and I do not believe it supports that antipattern (you want to build a `list` and call `''.join` at the end).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I meant that CPython is the only implementation with this optimization. I realize the word order in my sentence makes this ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPython, the reference implementation of Python, has an optimization for repeated concatenation of strings that is keeping your performance close to `O(n)` here. It's [a *brittle* optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40996801/364696), and [PEP 8's very first programming recommendation tells you not to rely on it](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Code should be written in a way that does not disadvantage other implementations of Python (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, Cython, Psyco, and such).

> For example, do not rely on CPython’s efficient implementation of in-place string concatenation for statements in the form `a += b` or `a = a + b`. This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for some types) and isn’t present at all in implementations that don’t use refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the `''.join()` form should be used instead. This will ensure that concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

It works because the optimization handles the specific case of a concatenation occurring where the left-hand side is being reassigned and there is only one reference to that string, so it can directly `realloc` the string's storage and mutate it in place, rather than constructing a new string. But as noted, it's brittle even on CPython, and not available at all on other implementations of Python, so avoid it.

Comment: Could you provide some example that would not be optimized then (or way to just disable that optimizations)?

Comment: @kosciej16: `res = res + "a" + "b"` breaks it (while `res += "a" + "b"` wouldn't break it, even if one of those literals was a variable containing a `str`). So does adding `garbage = res` before or after the concatenation within the loop. As does any function call involving `res` in that loop that might hold a reference to it for any reason (I think the I/O layers sometimes hold such a reference, but it's highly dependent on the state of the I/O buffers). Or if you switch from concatenating `str` to concatenating `bytes` (in Py3) or `unicode` (in Py2).

Comment: It works, thanks!