# Does the String.join() function run in linear time?

Tags: java

Since strings are `immutable` in java, appending items one by one to an empty string will take `O(n^2)` time. Does the `String.join("/", arrayList);` method performs in the same way, or does it run in linear time?

Comment: `O(n2)`? Do you mean `O(2n)` (which is `O(n)`) or do you mean `O(n^2)`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817290/string-join-vs-other-string-concatenation-operations

Comment: It runs in `O(n^2)` non-amortized and `O(n)` amortized.

Comment: `StringJoiner`, likewise as `StringBuilder`, do not operate on `String`s internally. They work on a `char[]`, which is **mutable**. By that, they bypass the performance hit you mentioned. They go to `String` only if you demand it, by calling `toString()`. That is the reason why you should prefer `StringBuilder` and `StringJoiner` if you are building up a string over multiple lines, for example over a loop.

Answer (score 3):

It runs in amortized `O(n)` time for Java 8.

This is the source code for `String.join`:

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter,
        Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter);
    Objects.requireNonNull(elements);
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    for (CharSequence cs: elements) {
        joiner.add(cs);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

As one can see, there is only one loop required.

`joiner.add` calls `StringBuilder.append`, which runs in amortized `O(1)` time, as it only has to set an element of an array. However, if the size becomes too large, it will have to expand its internal array and copy over all the elements already appended. See the relevant source code for `AbstractStringBuilder` below.

```
@Override
public AbstractStringBuilder append(CharSequence s) {
    if (s == null)
        return appendNull();
    if (s instanceof String)
        return this.append((String)s);
    if (s instanceof AbstractStringBuilder)
        return this.append((AbstractStringBuilder)s);

    return this.append(s, 0, s.length());
}
@Override
public AbstractStringBuilder append(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
    if (s == null)
        s = "null";
    if ((start < 0) || (start > end) || (end > s.length()))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "start " + start + ", end " + end + ", s.length() "
            + s.length());
    int len = end - start;
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    for (int i = start, j = count; i < end; i++, j++)
        value[j] = s.charAt(i);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minimumCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minimumCapacity - value.length > 0) {
        value = Arrays.copyOf(value,
                newCapacity(minimumCapacity));
    }
}
```

`StringJoiner.toString` calls `StringBuilder.toString`, which runs in `O(n)` time, as it has to copy of the array of characters to create a new `String`.

This is the source code for `StringBuilder.toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

The `String` constructor copies the elements of the `char` array using `Arrays.copyOfRange` in `O(n)` time:

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count <= 0) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
        }
        if (offset <= value.length) {
            this.value = "".value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

Comment: What about `joiner.add(cs)`. You have to convince that this runs in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code for String.join() in Java 8.

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter);
    Objects.requireNonNull(elements);

    // Number of elements not likely worth Arrays.stream overhead.
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);

    for (CharSequence cs: elements) {
        joiner.add(cs);
    }

    return joiner.toString();
}
```

Here is the source code for StringJoiner.add()

```
public StringJoiner add(CharSequence newElement) {
    // prepareBuilder() returns a StringBuilder
    prepareBuilder().append(newElement);
    return this;
}
```

As we can see, join() calls add() n times, and add runs in constant time (time to create StringBuilder + append 1 item), so String.join() *should* run in O(n) time.

Comment: You are missing a small but important detail. `StringJoiner.add` runs only amortized in `O(1)`, without an amortized analysis, it actually runs in `O(n)` since it is a dynamic array that might sometimes need to expand its internal capacity.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#ensureCapacity(int)) is the function from `StringBuilder` which does the capacity checking and array copy. It works by doubling the array size every time a capacity increase is needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 14

Looking at the current source code (Java 14), the correct answer is that it runs in `O(n^2)` **non-amortized** but `O(n)` **amortized** (see [Wikipedia#Amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)).

Here are the relevant snippets:

- [String#join](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2429-L2437) - a simple loop over all entries in the array, calling `joiner.add(...)` with a `StringJoiner`
- [StringJoiner#add](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ac4f14c386a74d1f52d66690cd7e0941cbc1c177/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/StringJoiner.java#L199-L211) - a simple set-call on the internal array `elts[size++] = elt;` but it has to ensure the array has enough capacity, eventually doubling it `Arrays.copyOf(elts, 2 * size);` (dynamic array)
- [Arrays#copyOf](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ac4f14c386a74d1f52d66690cd7e0941cbc1c177/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L3508-L3516) - this obviously runs in `O(n)` when called, it has to copy the whole old array into the new array. Although this call benefits a lot from the typical array optimizations, cache locality and similar.

This code represents a pretty common standard implementation of a **dynamic array** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)), such as `ArrayList`. Addition technically runs in `O(n)` but if we consider amortized analysis, it is `O(1)` as the resizing only has to be done rarely, increasing the mathematical potential until the next resize has to be made.

---

### Java 8

Interestingly, the source code for the class has changed. In Java 8 the `StringJoiner` was build on top of a `StringBuilder`, see the `add` method:

- [StringJoiner#add](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/StringJoiner.java#l184) - `prepareBuilder().append(newElement);`

However, `StringBuilder` internally also works based on a *dynamic array*:

- [StringBuilder#append](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#l135) - forward to super class
- [AbstractStringBuilder#append](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#l417) - which again calls `ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);` to ensure that the internal array has enough capacity
- [AbstractStringBuilder#ensureCapacityInternal](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#l118) - calling `expandCapacity` if needed
- [AbstractStringBuilder#expandCapacity](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#l128) - and here is our offender again, `int newCapacity = value.length * 2 + 2;` and then `Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);`

Answer (score 0):

`String.join()` use `StringBuilder` internally. `StringBuilder` internally makes use of a resizable array and an index that indicates the position of the last cell used in the array. When a new String is appended, its characters are copied to the end of the array and the index shifted to the right. If the internal array is full, its size is doubled.

Array expansion and the associated copy of characters is performed occasionally, when the array is full. Asymptotically for doubled the size as an expansion factor, the resize operation does not occur so often and `StringBuilder#append(String)` thus takes `O(1)` amortized time. Consequently, the whole joining list of item has a complexity in `O(n)`.

So, it's `O(n)`